# Sorting Files by date

Tags: c#, .net

I am using such code to compare files to sort by date..

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(name1);
FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(name2);
if (f.Exists && f1.Exists)
   output = DateTime.Compare(f.LastWriteTime, f1.LastWriteTime);
```

Is there any better and faster way to sort by Date?

At a time i can compare only 2 items...

I could not sort by getting all files from directory.

Comment: If you can compare only 2 items at once, then you can't make it faster, without changing you program logic.

Answer (score 80):

You can use LINQ:

```
var sortedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\samples").GetFiles()
                                                  .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: oh snap, i love this solution!  for the noobs, to have the latest files at the top, use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`

Comment: AnyIdeas without using extension methods/LINQ because I'm targeting .NET 2.0

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful, my first time at LINQ!

Comment: `LastWriteTime` may return `{1/1/1601 3:30:00 AM}` if the file is not modified after initial creation! see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839158/2803565)

Answer (score 13):

```
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Temp");
    var result = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(t => t.LastWriteTime).ToList();
```

Comment: `LastWriteTime` may return `{1/1/1601 3:30:00 AM}` if the file is not modified after initial creation! see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839158/2803565)

Answer (score 10):

What about using Array.Sort ?

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("directory ", "*.*");
DateTime[] creationTimes = new DateTime[fileNames.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
    creationTimes[i] = new FileInfo(fileNames[i]).CreationTime;
Array.Sort(creationTimes, fileNames);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is another way of doing it for the whole directory:dateCompareFileInfo

```
if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_NAME))
{
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DIRECTORY_NAME);
     FileInfo[] logFiles = di.GetFiles("AN-10-log.txt*");

     DateCompareFileInfo dateCompareFileInfo = new DateCompareFileInfo();

     Array.Sort(logFiles, dateCompareFileInfo);
}
```

And the you need a new DateCompareFileInfo class that implements IComparer:

```
class DateCompareFileInfo : IComparer<FileInfo>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compare the last dates of the File infos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fi1">First FileInfo to check</param>
    /// <param name="fi2">Second FileInfo to check</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Compare(FileInfo fi1, FileInfo fi2)
    {
        int result;
        if (fi1.LastWriteTime == fi2.LastWriteTime)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        else if (fi1.LastWriteTime < fi2.LastWriteTime)
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result = -1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

IMPORTANT - When ordering by LastWriteTime, it should be noted that if the file has never been modified, this date may return 1601 or 1600.  Here is what MSDN says:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

If your timezone is PST, like me the date will actually be 12/31/1600.  To get around this and write more robust code you might consider something like this:

```
.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime.Year <= 1601 ? f.CreationTime : f.LastWriteTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the result to a readable class by the SSIS object:

```
var directory = Dts.Variables["User::SourceDir"].Value.ToString();
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
var result = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(t => t.LastWriteTime).ToList();
DataTable dsSorted = new DataTable();

DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Value");
dsSorted.Columns.Add(dc);
foreach (FileInfo item in result)
{
    DataRow dr = dsSorted.NewRow();
    dr[0] = directory  + item ;
    dsSorted.Rows.Add(dr);
}

// lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesSorted"].Value = dsSorted;

// MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesSorted"].Value.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have found from [MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f39a700-3afa-49c1-b246-101221cd2bd6/directorygetfiles-in-date-order?forum=csharpgeneral).

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\my-directory");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(@"*.*");
Array.Sort(files, (x, y) => Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare(x.LastWriteTime, y.LastWriteTime));
```

Comment: It's 'Comparer', not 'Compare'

Comment: @FINDarkside Thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: @Parrotmaster  I fixed the typo on 8/28.  Please kindly point out the typo if there is still any.  Thanks.  (I have also added the missing close parenthesis and semicolon at the end.)

Comment: My bad, I believed the Comparer<DateTime> to be a typo. I will delete my initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Compare LastWriteTimeUtc of FileInfos
private class FileInfoDateComparer : IComparer<FileInfo> {
    //
    public long direction = 1;
    //
    public FileInfoDateComparer( bool ascending ) {
        direction = ascending ? 1 : -1;
    }
    //
    public int Compare( FileInfo fi1, FileInfo fi2 ) {
        long d = direction * ( fi1.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks - fi2.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks );
        return d < 0 ? -1 : d > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
//
//
private static FileInfo[] SortByDate( FileInfo[] afi, bool ascending ) {
    if ( null != afi ) {
        if ( 0 < afi.Length ) {
            var c = new FileInfoDateComparer( ascending );
            Array.Sort( afi, c );
        }
    }
    return afi;
}
```